# Rails - Whitespace added to content of textarea on save

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying provide a textarea for the user to enter javascript.  Each time the form is saved more whitespace is appended throughout the content.  Any ideas how to ensure this doesn't happen?

Using Rails

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a meta-HTML framework such as HAML, you need to ensure that there's no indentation happening to the content of your  tag. While this is usually not a problem with ERB, you do need to be aware that whitespace inside the tag is submitted with the form.

Have a look at the source of your page to see what is rendered. It would be useful to append that to your question as a code snippet if possible.

Comment: This is the textarea I have:

<textarea class="code" wrap="hard" id="js" name="js"><%= @book.js %></textarea>

Comment: What does that look like when rendered into the page as HTML? That's where the trouble is. Vish also has an interesting remark.

Answer (score 1):

Add a hyphen to the inside of your final %> tag, to prevent Rails from adding a newline and some whitespace. And make sure there's no whitespace in the HTML, of course :)

e.g.

```
<%= <blah> -%>
```

instead of

```
<%= <blah> %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I converted the ERB to HAML and it works since that. (erubis 2.7.0, haml 4.0.4)